How do I tell which kit lens option is more all-purpose?
I have been shooting photos for a long time with a smartphone, and now I want to "gear up" to improve my skills. I mostly shoot landscapes but I'd also like to learn to do some portraits.
There's the option to buy a mirrorless Nikon Z fc either with a 28 mm (1:2.8) SE lens or with a 16-50 mm (1:3.5-6.3) VR lens. Purchasing the camera alone, without the kit lens, is not possible. Which one should I get as an all-purpose lens, considering that I'll also buy some specialist lenses?

Do you have any reason to select Z FC? There are cheaper Nikon APS-C cameras.

I love the vintage look of it, and the price difference isn't much. It reminds me of the camera my grandfather (a skilled photographer) owned, about 50 years ago. So I want it to be my first "serious" camera.

"Purchasing the camera alone, without the kit lens, is not possible." Maybe it depends on what region of the world you are in, but that claim is not true in the USA nor the UK.

I would say that "prime lens" and "all-purpose lens" are pretty much contradictions in terms.

Smartphone and DSLR camera photography are quite different. I mean the technical aspects. There is also quite a bit of learning curve with the camera. I started about six months back with a ZFC and 50mm prime lens (I had a chance to purchase them individually). I feel that a prime lens  (e.g., Nikkor Z 40mm f/2 prime) is a better option if you are a beginner. I know a lot of folks start with kit lenses (there are choices here). I also know there are sometimes price discounts when purchasing a kit lens. Good luck with your new equipment.

"...considering that I'll also buy some specialist lenses?" The devil is always in the details. What specialist lenses are you considering? How much 'overlap' would there be between those specific specialist lenses and each of the two lenses you're currently considering?

@osullic, the body-only option is out of stock on B&H at the moment. I think that's what the OP is running into. Also the kit lens on my OM-10 was a 50/1.8. [grin].

@inkista This is indeed the case.

Both of the kit lenses can be considered "all-purpose" lenses, just in different ways. Kit lenses are usually lower-cost all-purpose lenses. That's why they come in the box with the camera.
But let's turn this around and look at this from your smartphone experience.
On a smartphone you typically have three back cameras you use for taking photos: an ultrawide (0.5x zoom), the main lens (1x zoom), and maybe a telephoto option (3x or 5x zoom).
All of these lenses are "primes"; that is, lenses that don't actually change focal length or zoom (zooming on most phones is done by resizing/cropping, aka "digital zoom"). And most phone cameras have a maximum aperture (how wide the iris in the lens can be set) of around f/2.
The general equivalency of the main lens is 24mm, so all the #x zooms are relative to that. So, an ultrawide is roughly 12mm-equivalent, the main is 24mm-equivalent, and a tele is say 72mm (3x) or 120mm (5x).
But we can't compare these equivalent focal lengths (what those focal lengths were frame like on a full-frame or 35mm film camera) directly to focal lengths of lenses used for a Z fc, because the Z fc uses a smaller APS-C sensor with a 1.5x crop factor.
So, if we look at the two Z fc kit lenses:
Z 28mm f/2.8
This will frame at 28*1.5 => 42mm equivalency. Or similar to a 1.75x zoom lens would on your phone. It's sort of midway between the main and a 3x tele lens. At f/2.8 max. aperture, it's a stop slower than your phone lenses, but still fast enough for shooting handheld indoors without a flash. It will also let you blur backgrounds for portraits a bit more by giving a thinner depth of field (how much of the scene is in focus front-to-back).
This is, essentially, a "normal" fast prime that's not particularly wide or particularly tele. It can be used for walkaround shooting and portraits. It may be a little tight for landscape shooting or selfies, but you can use it for both.
Z 16-50mm f/3.5-6.3 VR
This lens actually zooms, with 16-50*1.5 => 24-75mm equivalency. So this can basically cover everything from the 1x main lens on a phone camera to a 3x tele lens with a continuous optical zoom range. It's more versatile on framing choices than the 28mm, allowing you to vary between both wide angle and short telephoto.
But the max. aperture of f/3.5-6.3 (f/3.5 at the 16mm wide end, and f/6.3 at the 50mm tele end) is slower than the f/2 of a smartphone lens, and may require noisier high ISO settings to shoot indoors handheld without a flash. It does have VR (vibration reduction) stabilization to help keep camera shake blur from handholding happening at lower shutter speeds. But it cannot help with blur from subject movement. Only a faster shutter speed can do that.
So which one is more "general purpose" depends on how you define "general purpose". Do you want more flexibility in framing (focal length)?  Or in the light conditions you can shoot in and depth of field (max. aperture)?
As a last note, while body-only packages of the Z fc appear to be out of stock at the moment, if you wait, it is likely to come back into stock or possibly be replaced with a newer model. But "body only" packages typically aren't for a first-time mirrorless owner to pick a lens a la carte, as much as they're for someone upgrading bodies not to be lumbered with YA kit lens.
When choosing your first lens, you are in something of a "chicken and the egg" dilemma: to know which lens you want, you need experience with lenses. A low-cost kit lens can give you that experience and a point of reference to figure out what it is you want in a lens in terms of focal length, max. aperture, or other features (focus motor, stabilization, macro capability, etc. etc.)

Maybe a minor factor could be lens re-sell value: I think it's easier to resell a 28 mm prime than a kit zoom, generally

Might be a good opportunity to learn the "two-steps-forward" method of zooming, to get a fixed lens. I love my flat 50, it forces me to move. The excellent aperture range and bokeh the simplistic buildup provides is also a boon.

@clabacchio, it's a consideration, but not part of the answer to the question. And throwing in a it lens with a body you're trying to sell can make it more attractive, so...

Whatever small loss one may incur in terms of image noise between using an f/2.8 or an f/3.5-6.3 lens on an APS-C sensor will still pale in comparison to the amount of noise due to the difference in sensor size between an APS-C sensor and a typical phone camera sensor. That is, even at the higher ISO needed to use f/6.3 on the APS-C sensor, there will be much less image noise than using f/2 on a 1/2.3" phone sensor at lower ISO.

This is a relatively easy choice: you buy the 16-50 zoom lens. You will want to zoom to a different focal length than 28 mm a lot more often than you'll need the extra low-light capabilities (especially because f/2.8 isn't even that fast for a prime lens).

Like all the other answers, I would agree, that the most general purpose lens (out of the two you mentioned) in terms of focal length is the zoom lens. It will be the one giving you the most flexibility with regard to composition, i.e. what you can fit into a frame given a certain distance to the subject (and thereby perspective).
The prime lens restricts you to one focal length, so you would have to "zoom with your feet". Changing your distance to the subject does change perspective, however, so zooming and walking is not equivalent (that is where this common expression falls apart).
Many people recommend starting out with a prime lens (if the goal is serious photography, that is), because it does force you to think about your subject and composition much more than a convenient zoom lens and it also makes you move around and discover new angles and perspectives. All of that is, of course, technically possible with a zoom lens as well.
I'm not familiar with the two lenses in question but generally speaking, a prime lens almost always yields better quality images (better sharpness, better contrast, lower distortion, lower aberrations / color fringing) when compared to a similarly priced (!) zoom lens. There are exceptions, however, so I would always recommend checking lens reviews before buying.
Have you thought about buying on the used market? Depending on where you live, there may be well-maintained and affordable lenses (and bodies) available, so you could get the body, zoom lens and maybe a portrait lens.
P.S.:
If someone (as in another answer) suggests a 50mm lens, they probably refer to a 35mm lens on APS-C, which has the same field of view (i.e. generally produces very similar images) to a 50mm lens on a full-frame camera. Focal lengths on APS-C have to be multiplied by 1.5 to get the full-frame equivalent.
The classic focal length for portraits is said to be 85mm (on full-frame), which is equivalent to about 56mm on APS-C, so the long end of your zoom lens would probably be somewhat suited for classic portraits. This is not to say that you cannot shoot portraits at any other focal length, of course.
P.P.S.:
The currently accepted answer implies, that you can just compare the f-numbers between your phone and the camera in question. I do not want to go into the details here, but let me just say that the f/2 lens on your phone is nowhere equivalent to an f/2 lens on an APS-C camera (at equivalent focal lengths). Buying an f/2.8 or even f/3.5 lens is NOT a downgrade in terms of depth of field (i.e. background blur) or low-light capability when compared to the phone. At least when considering physics. Phones do employ many tricks today (such as combining multiple shots into one), so that comparison does not always hold anymore. Those tricks come with their own caveats, as I'm sure you have found out already.

An all-purpose lens is the kit lens. That is why a camera comes with it.
For a portrait lens, you want one with a wide aperture, F1.8, and a medium-long focal range. A standard recommendation as your first prime lens is one 50mm. But you probably want to explore a longer focal length like 85mm.
For landscapes, define what type of landscapes. If you want to maximize sharpness you also need to take a look for a prime wide angle lens.
